# Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive integers such that $\frac{bc}{b+c}$, $\frac{ca}{c+a}$, $\frac{ab}{a+b}$ are integers. Show that $\gcd(a,b,c) >1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive integers such that $\frac{bc}{b+c}$, $\frac{ca}{c+a}$, $\frac{ab}{a+b}$ are integers. Show that $\gcd(a,b,c) >1$.

I can see that $\gcd(b,c)$, $\gcd(c,a)$, and $\gcd(a,b)$ are all greater than 1, but how can we show $\gcd(a,b,c)>1$? Thanks!

Comment: See for example [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1746498p11371103) for $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=d>1$, as you said , and use [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524292/proof-if-gcda-b-gcdb-c-gcda-c-d-then-gcda-b-c-d) to conclude that $\gcd(a,b,c)=d$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You wrote "... for $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=d\gt 1$, as you said, ...". However, note the OP just wrote "... $\gcd(b,c)$, $\gcd(c,a)$, and $\gcd(a,b)$ are all greater than 1, ...", i.e., they *didn't* state they were all necessarily equal. Nonetheless, without making that assumption, the AoPS thread solution technique is related to at least one way, that I've determined, to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume $(a,b,c)=1$. Since $\frac{ab}{a+b}$ is a positive integer, we must have $(a,b)>1$. The reason is clear. If $(a,b)=1$, then:
$$(a+b,a)=(a+b,b)=(a,b)=1 \implies (a+b, ab)=1.$$

Now, suppose $a=dm$ and $b=dn$, where $d>1$ and $(m,n)=1$. We will have:
$$\frac{ab}{a+b}=\frac{dmn}{m+n};$$

but $(m+n, mn)=1$ because $(m,n)=1$. Therefore:
$$m+n|d \implies d=s(m+n), $$

where $s$ is a positive integer. So $a=(m+n)sm$ and $b=(m+n)sn$.

Since we have assumed that $(a,b,c)=1$, we must have: $(c, (m+n)s)=1$.

Similarly, since $\frac{ac}{a+c}$ is a positive integer, we have:

$$(a,c)=((m+n)sm, c)=(m,c)>1.$$

Suppose $c=hc_1$ and $m=hm_1$, where $h$ is a positive integer and $(c_1,m_1)=1$. So,

$$\frac{ac}{a+c}=\frac{h((m+n)sm_1)c_1}{c_1+(m+n)sm_1},$$

but $(c_1, (m+n)sm_1)=1$; as a result, $((m+n)sm_1c_1, (m+n)sm_1+c_1)=1$. Thus, we must have:

$$c_1+(m+n)sm_1|h \\ \implies h \geq  c_1+(m+n)sm_1  > m,$$

which is a contradiction because:

$$m=hm_1 \geq h.$$

Comment: Thanks! In this way, it seems that we only need $\frac{ab}{a+b}$ and $\frac{ac}{a+c}$ to be an integer